# Using arrows to generate deeply nested records

Tags: haskell, arrows

I have a deeply nested record which I am trying to rebuild from the database. For example, `A` contains many `B` records. `B` records have many `C` records. `C` has many `D`s. I have functions to query the children of each type of object (`f0`, `f1`, and `f2` below).

```
f0 :: A -> [B]
f1 :: B -> [C]
f2 :: C -> [D]
```

I am looking for an elegant way to implement `f3`.

```
f3 :: A -> (A, [(B, [(C, [D])])])
```

I've read a little bit on [Arrows](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base//Control-Arrow.html) and it feels like they might be a good fit. However, I keep hitting a road block when I try to combine them.

I've started with something like this:

```
f4 :: A -> (A, [B])
f4 = id &&& f0
```

which gets me to the first level. However, I'm at a loss to find a way to chain that to another arrow which would map `[B]`, return `[(B, [C])]`and use that as the second element of the original tuple.

I'm a bit new to Haskell, so please let me know if I need to include any additional information.

Thanks!

**Update**

Modifying sclv's answer slightly, I now have

```
data A = A
data B = B
data C = C
data D = D

f0 :: A -> [B]
f0 = undefined

f1 :: B -> [C]
f1  = undefined

f2 :: C -> [D]
f2 = undefined

pairFun f = id &&& f

foo :: A -> (A, [(B, [C])])
foo = fmap (map (pairFun f1)) . pairFun f0
```

I still can't wrap my mind around how to combine the last function (`f2`).

**Final update**

Thanks to sclv, it turns out this can be done like this:

```
foo = (fmap . map) ((fmap . map) (pairFun f2) . pairFun f1) . pairFun f0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this should work (untested):

```
pairFun f = id &&& f

foo = (fmap . map) ((fmap . map) (pairFun f2) . pairFun f1) . pairFun f0
```

edit: one way to think about this, by the way, is using conal's model of semantic editor combinators -- http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators

Comment: Awesome, that definitely gets me closer. My type-fu is failing me, though. I have `foo = fmap (map (pairFun f1)) . pairFun f0` which means `foo` now has type `foo :: A -> (A, [(B, [C])])`. So close. I can't wrap my mind around how to combine the last function. Ideas?

Comment: @RJRegenold see my edit. I forgot we're `fmap`ing two levels in (the fmap works on the second element of the pair (you can spell it `second` instead, using the arrow library if you prefer), but we need the map to take us into the list too.

Comment: Beautiful. I had to switch the `(map . fmap)` to `(fmap . map)`, which I think makes sense, as we're mapping over the second element of the tuple. Thanks for the info about `fmap` and `second`. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Conal Elliott also covers "deep arrows" in one of his papers, "Tangible Functional Programming".

Comment: Great article. Thanks for the link. Also, here is a link to the paper @stephentetley mentioned: http://conal.net/papers/Eros/